# Snapping line to polygon border using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, python-2.7

I want to snap the line (completely present inside the polygon) to polygon boundary. I tried create 10 m buffer on line start and end point to get polygon and check intersection between line and polygon it returns all the line vertices as intersected. I want only intersection of line to polygon boundary. I use the following code to get an intersection. My aim is if line is 10 m distance to border snap to line border.

```
 intersection = line.geometry().intersection(polygon.geometry())
 intersectstr= intersection.exportToWkt()
 gem=QgsGeometry.fromWkt(intersectstr)
 intersetpnt=gem.asPoint()
```

[image]